# Scikit-learn FunctionTransformer in a train-test setting

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Given two arrays `x_train` and `x_test`, I want to create a custom sklearn transformer that during fitting, it should learn which columns should be transformed. In particular, I want to log-transform the columns which are right-skewed (skewness > 1).

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
x_train = pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[1,4],[1,5],[1,4],[3,6],[4,5]])
x_test = pd.DataFrame([[1,4],[2,4],[5,4],[6,4],[10,8],[7,12]])

print(x_train.skew())
print(x_test.skew())
```

- `x_train[0]` <- skewed
- `x_train[1]` <- not skewed
- `x_test[0]` <- not skewed
- `x_test[1]` <- skewed

So, ideally, the transformer should transform only the column 0, but not column 1, for both `x_train` and `x_test`. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def log_skewed(df): #function that log-transforms skewed columns
    skewness = df.skew()
    for i,s in enumerate(skewness):
        if s>1:
            df[i] = np.log(df[i])
    return df
            
transformer = FunctionTransformer(log_skewed)
transformer.fit(x_train)
x_train_new = transformer.transform(x_train)
x_test_new = transformer.transform(x_test)
```

### The problem is that:

This transformation transforms different columns of `x_train` and `x_test`.

How can I "teach" to the transformer, during fitting, which columns will we transformed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `FunctionTransformer` for this scenario since its `fit()` method merely checks the input `X` for the correct type and shape. In your example, you do not (and actually cannot) save the information which columns to transform when fitting the transformer to `x_train`.

You have to define a custom transformer that does what you want. During fit, it should learn which columns are skewed. And when calling `transform`, it should transform the corresponding columns. A solution could look like this:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np


class SkewnessTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self._columns = None

    @property
    def columns_(self):
        if self._columns is None:
            raise Exception('SkewnessTransformer has not been fitted yet')
        return self._columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        skewness = X.skew()
        self._columns = skewness.loc[skewness > 1].index.values
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X[self.columns_] = np.log(X[self.columns_])
        return X
```

For your data, you can then use it like this:

```py
x_train = pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[1,4],[1,5],[1,4],[3,6],[4,5]])
x_test = pd.DataFrame([[1,4],[2,4],[5,4],[6,4],[10,8],[7,12]])

skt = SkewnessTransformer()

print(skt.fit_transform(x_train))
# output
          0  1
0  0.000000  5
1  0.000000  4
2  0.000000  5
3  0.000000  4
4  1.098612  6
5  1.386294  5

print(skt.transform(x_test))
# output
          0   1
0  0.000000   4
1  0.693147   4
2  1.609438   4
3  1.791759   4
4  2.302585   8
5  1.945910  12

print(skt.columns_)
# output: [0]
```

There are however some constraints to this solution:

- the transformer expects a pandas `DataFrame` as input
- it expects the column names in the index of the output of `skew()`
- once fitted, the inputs must have the same column names
- the transformer only checks for skewness > 1 (this was but according to your example)

If any of these are undesirable, the solution needs to be modified accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't set any attributes in `__init__` that aren't in the signature ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html?highlight=custom%20estimator#parameters-and-init)).  I think skipping the `property` and just having the `fit`-set `columns_` would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach uses the callable option of the column specification in `ColumnTransformer`.  At `fit` time, the callable checks for skewed columns, and saves the output to determine which columns to apply the log to at `transform` time.

```py
def skew_identifier(X):
    return X.skew() > 1

tfmr = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('log', FunctionTransformer(np.log), skew_identifier)
    ],
    remainder='passthrough',
)
```

As in [afsharov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68606907/10495893), this assumes pandas as input, but only for `.skew()` to work.  To work on numpy arrays, you could use `scipy.stats.skew` instead.

You can inspect which columns got identified as skewed as `tfmr.transformers_[0][2]` (0'th transformer, 2 is the column specification).  `tfmr.transformers[0][2]` contains the original callable.  `tfmr._columns` could also be useful, but is private and so may change.